# Cropping image with intervention

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4, intervention

I'm trying to crop the image before or after it's uploaded, I didn't have any luck so far. before we start, I should say I have no experience with this stuff. here is the code I tried and didn't work:

```
$file->move('storage/profil', $fileNameToStore)->crop(100, 100, 25, 25);
```

I do not understand how this thing should work but tried some basic methods to work it around. there are examples in the website like:

```
$img = Image::make('public/foo.jpg');
$img->crop(100, 100, 25, 25);
```

But when I try it, it eather does not find make or crop.

```
use Intervention\Image\Facades\Image;
```

is included at the top. I think this shouldn't be an issue. any help is appreciated in advance.

Here is the controller if you need it:

```
$file = $request->file('userImg');

$extension = $request->file('userImg')->getClientOriginalExtension();
$fileNameToStore = uniqid() . '.' . $extension;

$file->move('storage/profil', $fileNameToStore);

$user->userImg = $fileNameToStore;

//    $img = Image::make('public/foo.jpg');
//    $img->crop(100, 100, 25, 25);

$user->update();
```

> Laravel 5.4

Comment: Try `use Image;` also you can use resize **if** you only want to resize the photo and not actually cut off part of it.

Comment: I want to cut it, cuz in some pages the image is circule, if I don't cut it it will look like an egg

Comment: Have you tried using `use Image;`?

Comment: yeap it throwes ***Image source not readable***

Comment: Well the problem is in your saving location, would you mind share your full code here?

Comment: I addded controller  code

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$img->crop(100, 100)->encode('png', 25)->trim()->save(sprintf("%s/logo.png",$path));
```

Using trim might solve your issue .

Update:

Try this code,

```
if ($request->hasFile('userImg')) { $userImg = $request->file('userImg'); $filename = 'userImg' . '-' . time() . '.' . $userImg->getClientOriginalExtension(); $location = public_path('storage/profil'); $request->file('userImg')->move($location, $filename); $user->userImg = $filename; }
```

Comment: Whow this confuses me so much :D

Comment: Put this code before your update and tell me what you will get with this? `dd($user->userImg);`

Comment: Btw I try to upload the image with ajax, so it throwes ***Method crop does not exist***

Comment: Ajax uploading is something else and requires to know your function,route,ajax etc. Is out of what we're discussing now, what was the result of `dd`?

Comment: before dd it throw me **method crop does not exist

Comment: But I'm not see any crop method in your controller except the one is commented, how it gives you that error?!

Comment: there is one ***$img->crop(100, 100)****

Comment: when I leave crop out than it says method encode does not exist

Comment: That is commented by // it shouldn't give you error! Anyway remove that just till we see the result of dd.

Comment: Lol i removed everything till save and now its saying save does not exist

Comment: Bro, just remove or comment `crop part` the rest let it be as it is.

Comment: Can you check the controller code I have at the top? I might be doing stuff wrong, but no matter what I leave there, it throws method does not exist

Comment: I tried to do dd, couldn't have it cuz of the ajax, but this code uploads the image succesfully

Comment: Forget about dd, try see if with this code you can successfully uploading an image then we try to add crop in it :)

Comment: Yeap it uploads the image

Comment: Perfect, now add crop after `move($location, $filename)` in my code and see if it works.

Comment: now it says ***Call to undefined method Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File::crop()***

Comment: @maforits I'm still having this issua, didnt work on that issue since than. can you come and help a little?